# YouTube API v.3 with GoogleCredential (OAuth2): My YouTube credentials get "Insufficient Permission" when createPlaylist or uploadVideo

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

The following code does fine when I search for videos using Google's YouTube API (version 3) but fails when attempting:

```
Playlist youTubePlaylist = new Playlist();
youTubePlaylist.setSnippet(playlistSnippet);
youTubePlaylist.setStatus(playlistStatus);
YouTube.Playlists.Insert command = youTube.playlists().insert("snippet,status", youTubePlaylist);
youTubePlaylist.setKey("AI...1IU");
youTubePlaylist.execute();
```

On the credential step I do get an accessToken but failure happens on youTubePlaylist.execute():

```
{
  "access_token" : "ya29...DSoQ",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "token_type" : "Bearer"
}

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at ...publication.youtube.YouTubeAPIVersion3Connector.execute(YouTubeAPIVersion3Connector.java:107)
    at ...publication.youtube.YouTubeAPIVersion3ServiceImpl.createPlaylist(YouTubeAPIVersion3ServiceImpl.java:119)
```

The authentication is done as follows:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
File privateKeyP12 = new File(getYouTubeConfigDirectory(), "/private-key-youtube-v3.p12");
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
 .setTransport(httpTransport)
 .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
 .setServiceAccountId("99...@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
 .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.list(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY, YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_UPLOAD))
 .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(privateKeyP12)
 .setClientSecrets("9...42.apps.googleusercontent.com", "DH...w8")
 .setRefreshListeners(getRefreshListeners())
 .build();
}
return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(googleAppAccountName).build();
```

Keep in mind, **I am NOT performing YouTube operations on behalf of another user**. My web application is managing videos on its own YouTube channel. What I've done already:

- via Google Cloud Console, I enabled YouTube v3 API, created an app with permission to edit
- I generated p12 private key file which is loaded by code above
- I use API key on all operations

What am I missing? For example:
 - what am I supposed to do with the Public Key Fingerprint provided by Google Cloud Console?
 - am I properly setting setServiceAccountScopes() with only YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY and YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_UPLOAD?
 - Is there some way I can control permissions beyond setting "Can Edit" on Cloud Console for email: 99...91i@developer.gserviceaccount.com?

Part of my frustration is that all code samples provided by YouTube v3 API site involve spinning up a "headless" AWT toolkit. All my app wants to do is authenticate using its own YouTube account.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Service accounts are not supported in Data API v3. Please create a project id in [cloud console](https://cloud.google.com/console#/project) and use your client secret and id.

Although we are aware of the need, we don't have news about this availability at this point.

[Here are our Java samples, that can guide you](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-java).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The Auth.java in code samples includes step to "Build the local server and bind it to port 8080": new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build().  Is there a way I can make this work without firing up local server?